# Image or Video not getting rendered in Dash App

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

Below is the code of my dash app. Issue is across all browser types the its either rendering empty thumbnails for images or empty video player for video images.

All these files are working as when I open them manually from my folder they work properly.

```
import os
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
from dash.dependencies import State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP], title='Renderer')

app.layout = html.Div([
dbc.Row(
    dbc.Col(
        html.Div([
            html.H1("Photo and Video Viewer"),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='file-type-dropdown',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'Photos', 'value': 'photo'},
                    {'label': 'Videos', 'value': 'video'}
                ],
                value='photo'
            ),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='file-dropdown',
                options=[],
                multi=True
            ),
            html.Div(id='file-display')
        ]),
        width=6),
),
])


@app.callback(
Output('file-dropdown', 'options'),
Output('file-dropdown', 'value'),
Input('file-type-dropdown', 'value')
)

def update_file_dropdown(selected_type):
folder_path = 'D:/New Folder'  # Replace with the path to your folder
if selected_type == 'photo':
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', 
'.gif'))]
else:
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith(('.mp4', '.avi', '.mkv', 
'.mov'))]

file_options = [{'label': file, 'value': file} for file in files]

return file_options, None


@app.callback(
 Output('file-display', 'children'),
 Input('file-dropdown', 'value'),
 State('file-type-dropdown', 'value')
)

def display_selected_files(selected_files, selected_type):
 folder_path = 'D:/New Folder'  # Replace with the path to your folder

if not selected_files:
    return "Select files to display."

file_content = []

for file in selected_files:
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)

    if selected_type == 'photo':
        if file_path.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif')):
            file_content.append(html.Img(src=file_path, style={'max-width': '100%'}))
    else:
        if file_path.endswith(('.mp4', '.avi', '.mkv', '.mov')):
            file_content.append(html.Video(src=file_path, controls=True))

return file_content


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run_server(debug=True, port=8060)
```

Rendering of image for reference:
[image]

Rendering of video for reference:
[image]

Where am I going wrong.

Please guide.

Regards
Sudhir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security concerns, (by default, most) browsers are not allowed to load local resources when `window.location` is *not* a local resource.

In your situation, the rendered html page contains images/videos that are referenced using a local file path, eg. `<img src="D:/New Folder/image.png">`, but since the page is served via http from `http://hostname:8060`, the browser is not allowed to use the `file://` scheme to load them (it would be though if the page were loaded from `file:///path/to/some/page.html`).

So you need to serve those resources via http as well : by default, Dash automatically serves all of the files that are included in the `assets` folder in the root of your app directory, so you can create this folder and put in it all the assets (js, css, medias, etc.) required by you app, then in your code you can use the asset url instead of the local file path :

```py
# file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
url = dash.get_asset_url(file)
```

NB. The options regarding assets can be set via the Dash constructor.

@see [Embedding Images in Your Dash Apps](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-enterprise/static-assets?de-version=5.1#embedding-images-in-your-dash-apps)

Comment: Thanks .. for the solution but was not able to accept as I was out of action.