# Dash app not displaying JPG images on browser

Tags: python, image, plotly-dash

I have images in a folder called images. I want to display those in Dash app on the browser.

Here is the code I  used:

```
    import dash
    from dash import Dash, html
    import os

    asst_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "images")
    app= Dash(__name__, assets_folder=asst_path)
    print(f"{asst_path}/img1.jpg")
    app.layout = html.Div([
        html.Img(src=app.get_asset_url(f"http://{asst_path}/img1.jpg")),
        html.Img(src=app.get_asset_url(f"{asst_path}/img2.jpg"))
    ])

   if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(debug=True)
```

But the images are not displayed.
[image]

The link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77378218/image-or-video-not-getting-rendered-in-dash-app) states that I need to serve the resources via http as well : by default, Dash automatically serves all of the files that are included in the assets folder in the root of your app directory but I am not sure what it is that I am doing wrong. Thanks for help

Comment: This `asst_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "images")` makes `asst_path` the local file system path of the file - that's not the same as the URL path that would be needed to access it from the browser. Depending on how you're hosting the app, only the latter part of that path would match, and you'd need some other start to it, for example `http://127.0.0.1:8050/files/some/dir/img1.jpg'.  Start by trying to open the image in the browser directly, with the URL that you think should lead to it - once that works, figure out how to generate that correct link from your code.

Comment: file:///Users/nate/dir1/dir2/dash-app/images/img1.jpg . If I open my image using Google chrome, this is what I see

Comment: When you are using the `file://` protocol, you're just telling the browser to load a file directly from a location it can see, completely circumventing your web application. That wouldn't work from any computer that doesn't have the file in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dash automatically serves all files in the assets folder. So in-app.get_asset_url(), you only need to pass the file name, not the full path or URL. Here's the corrected code:

```
import dash
from dash import Dash, html
import os

asst_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "images")
app= Dash(__name__, assets_folder=asst_path)

# Correct usage of app.get_asset_url()
# Replace with your image filename
image_filename = 'Figure_1.png'  
image_src = app.get_asset_url(image_filename)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Img(src=image_src),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: I already tried this.  Even by using your code and replacing the image name,Still not able to see the output image in browser.

Comment: are your image names and the asset folder names correct? I tested this on my PC and this works

Comment: @NoviceB `asst_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "images")` assumes the path to your image directory _relative to the current working directory_ is "images", ie. let say this "images" dir is in the same dir as app.py, if you run the script with `cd path/to/your/app/` and then `python app.py` it should work; but if you run the script with `python path/to/your/app/app.py` it won't, you would need to set the relative path according to the cwd with `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "path/to/your/app/images")` to make it work, but you don't want to hardcode a local path into your app so use the 1st method.